# error in use application from servise chaining in wso2 esb

Tags: c#, xml, wso2, esb

i have a service chaining in wso2 esb and now i want for a application to send and recceiev message from that but i have an error :

```bsh
The content type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 361 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><MultiServiceResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><MultiServiceResult>121</MultiServiceResult></MultiServiceResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have sent a soap12 request for the service which expects a soap11 request.
Invoke the service using a soap11 request and you will be able to get rid of this issue.